# traefik https gives 404 error, http works normally even though my secure port is configured correctly

Tags: java, docker-compose, microservices, devops, traefik

My problem is my setup is running locally completely fine, when I go to setup staging environment with the same everything just changed the required stuff needed for staging environment

the https doesn't work correctly even though it suppose to be set up correctly in the below example

I am using wildcard certs that are correctly generated no problem there

the confusing point do I need to put tls cert generation on each and every router?

or what I'm missing

I would appreciate your input if you have got a problem like that

I want it to work on https as normal as HTTP

this is my docker-compose.yml file for staging environment:

```yaml
    version: "3"
    
    volumes:
      staging_mongo_data: {}
      staging_mongo_data_backups: {}
      staging_mysql_data: {}
      staging_mysql_data_backups: {}
      staging_openfire_data: {}
      staging_traefik: {}
      staging_example_files: {}
    
    
    services:
      tomcat: &tomcat
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: compose/staging/tomcat/Dockerfile
        image: example_staging_tomcat
        depends_on:
          - mongo
        volumes:
    #      - .:/app
          - staging_example_files:/home/example/files
        env_file:
          - .envs/.staging/.main
          - .envs/.staging/.mongo
        ports:
          - "8080:8080"
    
      repnjs:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: compose/staging/repnjs/Dockerfile
        image: example_staging_repnjs
        restart: always
        depends_on:
          - mongo
        volumes:
          - ./example-student-report:/home/node/app
          - ./example-student-report/node_modules:/home/node/app/node_modules
        env_file:
          - .envs/.staging/.main
          - .envs/.staging/.mongo
        ports:
          - 3500:3500
    
    
    
      web-client:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: ./compose/staging/web-client/Dockerfile
        image: example_staging_web-client
        depends_on:
          - tomcat
          - repnjs
        restart: always
        volumes:
    #      - ./one-uni-web-client:/home/node/app
          - ./one-uni-web-client/node_modules:/home/node/app/node_modules
        env_file:
          - .envs/.staging/.main
        ports:
          - 4000:4000
    
    
      articles:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: ./compose/staging/articles/Dockerfile
        image: example_staging_articles
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
          - "0.0.0.0:8181:80"
        volumes:
          - ./example-articles:/var/www/html
        depends_on:
          - mysql
        env_file:
          - .envs/.staging/.main
    
      mongo:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: compose/staging/mongo/Dockerfile
        image: example_staging_mongo
        volumes:
          - ./compose/staging/mongo/init-mongo.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-mongo.js:ro
          - ./compose/staging/mongo/conf/mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf
          - staging_mongo_data:/data/db
          - staging_mongo_data_backups:/backups
        env_file:
          - .envs/.staging/.mongo
        ports:
          - '27017-27019:27017-27019'
        environment:
    #     - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=database
          - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=user
          - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    
      mysql:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: compose/production/mysql/Dockerfile
        restart: always
        command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
        image: example_production_mysql
        volumes:
    #      - ./compose/production/mysql/conf/:/etc/mysql/conf.d/
          - staging_mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
          - staging_mysql_data_backups:/backups
        env_file:
          - .envs/.staging/.mysql
        ports:
          - '3306:3306'
        environment:
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    
    
      openfire:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: compose/staging/openfire/Dockerfile
        restart: always
        image: example_staging_openfire
        volumes:
          - ./compose/staging/openfire/etc/openfire:/etc/openfire
          - staging_openfire_data:/var/lib/openfire
    
        env_file:
          - .envs/.staging/.openfire
        ports:
          - '9090:9090'
          - '7070:7070'
        depends_on:
          - mysql
    
      assets:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: compose/staging/assets/Dockerfile
        # nginx config
        image: example_staging_assets
        volumes:
          - ./compose/staging/assets/files:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
          - '8282:80'
    
    
      traefik:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: ./compose/staging/traefik/Dockerfile
        image: example_staging_traefik
        depends_on:
          - tomcat
          - repnjs
          - web-client
        volumes:
          - staging_traefik:/etc/traefik/acme
        ports:
          - "0.0.0.0:80:80"
          - "0.0.0.0:443:443"
        env_file:
          - ./.envs/.staging/.main
```

this is my traefik.yml file for my setup

```yaml
    #traefik.yml
    
    
    log:
      level: INFO
    
    api:
      dashboard: true
      insecure: true
    
    entryPoints:
      web:
        # http
        address: ":80"
    
      web-secure:
        # https
        address: ":443"
    
    
    
    certificatesResolvers:
      letsencrypt:
        # https://docs.traefik.io/master/https/acme/#lets-encrypt
        acme:
          email: "info@example.com"
          storage: /etc/traefik/acme/acme.json
          # https://docs.traefik.io/master/https/acme/#httpchallenge
          dnsChallenge:
            provider: linode
            delayBeforeCheck: 0
          caServer: "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
    #      caServer: "https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
    
    
    http:
      routers:
        api:
          rule: "Host(`traefik.example.com`)"
          service: api@internal
    
        web-router:
          rule: "Host(`staging.example.com`)"
          entryPoints:
            - web
          middlewares:
            - redirect
          service: web-client
    
    
        web-secure-router:
          rule: "Host(`staging.example.com`)"
          entryPoints:
            - web-secure
          service: web-client
            # https://docs.traefik.io/master/routing/routers/#certresolver
          tls:
            certResolver: letsencrypt
            domains:
              - main: "example.com"
                sans:
                  - "*.example.com"
    
        tomcat-router:
          rule: "Host(`serverstaging.example.com`)"
          entryPoints:
            - web
          service: tomcat
    
        tomcat-secure-router:
          rule: "Host(`serverstaging.example.com`)"
          entryPoints:
            - web-secure
          service: tomcat
          tls:
    
        repnjs-router:
          rule: "Host(`repnjsstaging.example.com`)"
          entryPoints:
            - web
          service: repnjs
    
        repnjs-secure-router:
          rule: "Host(`repnjsstaging.example.com`)"
          entryPoints:
            - web-secure
          service: repnjs
          tls:
    
        ofweb-router:
          rule: "Host(`ofwebstaging.example.com`)"
          entryPoints:
            - web
          middlewares:
            - redirect
          service: ofweb
    
        ofweb-secure-router:
          rule: "Host(`ofwebstaging.example.com`)"
          entryPoints:
            - web-secure
          service: ofweb
          tls:
    
    
        articles-router:
          rule: "Host(`articles.staging.example.com`)"
          entryPoints:
            - web
          middlewares:
            - redirect
          service: articles
    
        articles-secure-router:
          rule: "Host(`articles.staging.example.com`)"
          entryPoints:
            - web-secure
          service: articles
          tls:
            # https://docs.traefik.io/master/routing/routers/#certresolver
            certResolver: letsencrypt
            domains:
              - main: "articles.staging.example.com"
    
        assets-router:
          rule: "Host(`assetsstaging.example.com`)"
          entryPoints:
            - web
          middlewares:
            - redirect
          service: assets
    
        assets-secure-router:
          rule: "Host(`assetsstaging.example.com`)"
          entryPoints:
            - web-secure
          service: assets
          tls: true
    
      middlewares:
        redirect:
          # https://docs.traefik.io/master/middlewares/redirectscheme/
          redirectScheme:
            scheme: https
            permanent: true
        redirect-www:
          redirectRegex:
            regex: "^https://www.(.*)"
            replacement: "https://$1"
            permanent: true
    
      services:
        tomcat:
          loadBalancer:
            servers:
              - url: http://tomcat:8080
        web-client:
          loadBalancer:
            servers:
              - url: http://web-client:4000
        repnjs:
          loadBalancer:
            servers:
              - url: http://repnjs:3500
        ofweb:
          loadBalancer:
            servers:
              - url: http://openfire:9090
        assets:
          loadBalancer:
            servers:
              - url: http://assets:8282
        articles:
          loadBalancer:
            servers:
              - url: http://articles:8181
    
    
    providers:
      # https://docs.traefik.io/master/providers/file/
      file:
        filename: /etc/traefik/traefik.yml
        watch: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and worked for me by adding

```
tls: true
```

to all the routers in the traefik.yml file